# Vaadin: Close Notofications by "close", "ok", or "x"?

Tags: javascript, notifications, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin and everything works fine, but there is one point I'm not happy about:

The notifications ( only show the message, but there is NOTHING which explains the user how to close it. Of course I can close it by clicking on it, but this is not intuitive in my opinion.

```
 Notification.show("message part one", "message part two", Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Is there a way to enable something like a close- or an ok-button for closing the notification? Or just an x at right top?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can display an X button.

See [Valo Theme Demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common), section notifications: use additional style "closable" (`ValoTheme.NOTIFICATION_CLOSABLE`).

Alternatively you could include text like "(click to close)" into your message.

Answer (score 1):

```
.v-Notification-error {
  @include valo-notification-error-style;
  @include valo-notification-closable-style;
}
```

Fixed it. Thanks to Steffen Harbich

Answer (score 0):

Tobi123's  solution gave a sass compile error in vaadin (version 7.6.6).

```
.v-Notification-error {
   @include valo-notification-error-style('v-Notification');
   @include valo-notification-closable-style;
}
```

Fixed it. Thanks to all.